# ClickOnce, checking and using updates from initial install location?

Tags: c#, .net-core, clickonce

We want to use ClickOnce to simplify deployment at our clients' premises. its a .net7 WPF app and clients have variable number of workstations. All clients use the same latest build. We had an idea to use ClickOnce, but ran into a problem.

Simply, how does one configure publishing profile to produce a manifest which would force launcher to check for the updates at the location from which it is first installed?

The VS publishing wizard requires that we specify the UNC or web location for update before build time, but we do not know where each client will store their setup, nor do we wish to start making separate publish profiles for every client (after managing to avoid that support nightmare for so long). The best approach would be for launcher to look at wherever it installed the app. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do something similar.